# get all calls to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reference

Is there a way to find all the functions that call another function?  (And then by extension, all the functions that call those functions, etc.)

My guess is it won't be possible for all cases, but certainly it could be done for most use cases, no?  Like if somebody defines their function as:

```
new Function('a','b', 'return a'+'+b;');
```

it might be more tricky to find inner references.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean static analysis of the source code? Or do you mean dynamic logging of whoever calls a function?

Comment: How would you count this call: `eval(prompt("Enter a function name") + "()"` ? :)  Are you looking for named calls only?

Comment: I'm just talking about analysis of the source code.  No fair generating functions at run time.

Comment: If you just need a simplistic view then just grep for the name. If you need a more correct view (you can assign function names to other variables), then, well you probably can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *arguments.caller* but it's deprecated. *Function.caller* is replacement but you need function name - I'd use *arguments.callee* or directly the name.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller

Comment: This is nice, but I was hoping to be able to apply it to any program without having to have to add a bunch of arguments.callee statements.  Essentially I want for javascript what is available for C# in Visual Studio.

Comment: Than I would try something with Function's prototype and call and/or apply methods - trying to create a wrapper for every call to every function. But it seams hard/very hard/imposible :D. It rather easy to do it on per function basis, but that's not what you want. There is also possibility to throw+catch and log+save stack trace. Anyhow JS is not C# ;) - but I guess that's true for any 2 languages :D

Answer (score 1):

In addition to its excellent *outline* view, Eclipse lets you "focus" the calls of a function in the source by selecting its declaration and then pressing F2. Appearances will be displayed in the right bar.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.  But I was looking to do it programmatically.